# How to add legend to Folium map created with GeoJson?

Tags: python, legend, caption, folium, choropleth

How do I add a color legend to the colormap of a Folium choropleth map created using the `folium.GeoJson` method?

I've tried adding `'caption='` to the colormap, but this generates an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Code follows below. It generates a correct choropleth if I remove `colormap.add_to(state_map)`, but there is no legend.  Likewise, including `"caption="` inside the colormap specifications does not display a legend.

```
import pandas
import folium
from branca.colormap import LinearColormap


# Specify the US state map geo data from file
state_geo = 'us-states.json'

# Define list of lists of state date to convert into pandas data frame
stateData = [
    ["AL", 1], ["AK", 2], ["AZ", 3], ["AR", 4], ["CA", 5], ["CO", 6], ["CT", 7], ["DE", 8], ["FL", 9], 
    ["GA", 1], ["HI", 2], ["ID", 3], ["IL", 4], ["IN", 5], ["IA", 1], ["KS", 2], ["KY", 3], ["LA", 4], 
    ["ME", 5], ["MD", 6], ["MA", 7], ["MI", 8], ["MN", 9], ["MS", 1], ["MO", 2], ["MT", 3], ["NE", 4], 
    ["NV", 5], ["NH", 6], ["NJ", 7], ["NM", 8], ["NY", 9], ["NC", 1], ["ND", 2], ["OH", 3], ["OK", 4], 
    ["OR", 3], ["PA", 4], ["RI", 6], ["SC", 6], ["SD", 2], ["TN", 8], ["TX", 8], ["UT", 8], ["VA", 5],
    ["VT", 5], ["WA", 6], ["WV", 7], ["WI", 8], ["WY", 9] 
    ]


# Find largest state total in order to set maximum value for darkets color
maxValue = 0
for s in stateData:
    if s[1] > maxValue:
        maxValue = s[1]

#convert list of lists into pandas dataframe
df_States = pandas.DataFrame(stateData, columns = ['State', 'Total']) 
df_statesDict = df_States.set_index('State')['Total']

#create color range for map, using the maximum state value found above
colormap = LinearColormap(
    colors=['white', 'red'], 
    index=[0 - round(maxValue * .1), round(maxValue * .9)], 
    vmin=df_States.min(), 
    vmax=df_States.max(),
    caption="Species"
    )

# Initialize the folium map
state_map = folium.Map(location=[37, -100], zoom_start=4.6,)

# Configure the chloropleth layer and add to map
folium.GeoJson(
    state_geo,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': colormap(df_statesDict[feature['id']]),
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 1,
        'fillOpacity': 0.8,
    }
    ).add_to(state_map)

#add caption to map
colormap.add_to(state_map)

# make the layer control box visible
folium.LayerControl().add_to(state_map)

# Save map to html
state_map.save('testingChoropleth.html')
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the classical `folium.Choropleth()` method?

Comment: @ sentence As I understand it (and I'm new to this...), the `folium.choropleth()` method only allows for up to 5 gradations of colors.  I wanted to use the full breadth of the color scale.  Also, I wanted to have unique tooltips for each regional polygon, which I couldn't achieve with the simpler method.  (I removed the tooltip code here for simplicity.)

Comment: @sentence How do you add legend to a choropleth map?

Comment: @HemanthBakaya Please, open a new question.

Comment: @sentence I can't; I have nothing to add in this question - to make it seem more complex or sophisticated - it's just gonna be filtered out and will not be allowed to post/submit by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems you need to have the color variable set to whatever colour scale you want.

In your code, try this:

```
# Configure the chloropleth layer and add to map
folium.GeoJson(
    state_geo,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'color': colormap(df_statesDict[feature['id']]),
        # 'color': 'black',
        'weight': 1,
        'fillOpacity': 0.8,
    }
    ).add_to(state_map)
```